# Watching changed in the service from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to listen to changes in my injected service (self-updating) in the controller. In the below example you'll find two `$watch` cases - one that works but I don't know exactly why and one that was obvious to me, yet doesn't work. Is the second example the right way to do it? Isn't that code duplication? What is the right way to do it?

Service:

```
app.factory("StatsService", [
    '$timeout', 'MockDataService',
    function ($timeout, MockDataService) {
        var service, timeout;
        timeout = 5000;
        service = {
            fetch: function () {
                // Getting sample data, irrelevant, however this is what updates the data
                return this.data = MockDataService.shuffle();
            },
            grab: function () {
                this.fetch();
                return this.update();
            },
            update: function () {
                var _this = this;
                return $timeout(function () {
                    return _this.grab();
                }, timeout);
            }
        };
        service.grab();
        return service;
    }
]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("StatsController", [
    '$scope', 'StatsService',
    function ($scope, StatsService) {
        var chart;
        $scope.stats = StatsService;
        $scope.test = function (newValue) {
            if (arguments.length === 0) {
                return StatsService.data;
            }
            return StatsService.data = newValue;
        };

        // This doesn't work
        $scope.$watch('stats', function (stats) {
            return console.log('meh');
        });

        // This works, don't know why
        $scope.$watch('test()', function (stats) {
            return console.log('changed');
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the third parameter for [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch): `objectEquality`

> Compare object for equality rather than for reference.

However if you're only interested in watching the returned data, then you should do:

```
$scope.$watch('stats.data', function (stats) {
    return console.log('meh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$rootScope` events. For example inside the service you could dispatch an event with `$rootScope.$broadcast("somethingFetched", data)` and catch it in the controller `$scope.$on("somethingFetched", function(event, data) { $scope.data = data })`.

More details you could find in the documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope